# Android studio error \Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Process 'command 'C:\Users\0\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

[external libraries pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPRp8.png)

I tried downloading different NDK bundle versions and all but nothing works, i tried putting some code to stop the mdk that didnt work, it keeps coming up anyway

What info do i need to provide to get help? 
Thanks

Comment: I don't know how the picture can be related to your question. Is there a `jni` directory in your project? Does your `build.gradle` refer to ndkBuild, CMake, or jni?

Comment: Hi there I fixed the problem, i had issues with the paths of OpenCV.mk had to edit the android.mk Thank you for answering

Comment: Maybe the wise move would be to delete the question. I believe that the error you found in your own code does not have a significant value for the community.

Comment: I believe this may shed a light to others to actually check the OpenCV.mk for instructions and may actually help someone.

Comment: Then at least you should explain your fix in detail, as a self-accepted answer. But if there is no significant difference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38105317/192373, your question will still be closed as duplicate.